# Apply changes to .vimrc to source file

Tags: vim

Im currently making a lot of changes in my .vimrc. At the same time Im also coding away on a project. To fix the new indentation and tabstop rules, and so on, I have to go through every line and re-indent them. This seems a little bit tedious.

Is there any way to apply the newest changes in my .vimrc to the whole source file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem seems to be that existing buffers do not get the updated (global) values of e.g. `'tabstop'`, because these are buffer-local options. Therefore, a simple `:so %` after editing the `~/.vimrc` isn't sufficient.

There are several possible approaches:

#### Use sessions

With the current Vim state persisted via `:mksession`, you can safely `:quit` Vim, restart it, `:so session.vim`, and have the identical editing state, but with the new settings applied (this requires that you `:set sessionoptions-=options`)

#### Manually apply

You can e.g. `:yank` the changed `:set tabstop=...` commands that you've edited and reapply them to all existing buffers, e.g. by moving there and `:@"`, or (if there are many) with the help of `:bufdo`.

---

Note that especially the indent settings can also be set from *ftplugins*, so your global settings may not be effective. You can check that for a buffer with `:verbose set tabstop?`.